# Confusion Metrix : Got an problem when I import the dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, confusion-matrix

As above, I can't describe the problem but I have result to show a problem. This is my code I used

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = keras.models.load_model(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Job\New_one\InceptionV3.h5")

data = {
    "y_Actual": [
        "Lablae",
        "Long",
        "Maejam(Ceiyng-saen-hnoy)",
        "Maejam(Ceiyng-saen-luang)",
        "Maejam(Hong-pi)",
        "Maejam(Hong-poi)",
        "Maejam(Kan-seiyn-sam)",
        "Maejam(Kom-rup-nk)",
        "Maejam(Kom-whua-mon-nai-nk-non)",
        "Maejam(Kud-kho-bed)",
        "Maejam(La-kon-klang)",
        "Maejam(La-kon-luang)",
        "Maejam(La-kon-noy)",
        "Maejam(Lay-kan-sam-aew)",
        "Maejam(Nak-kum)",
        "Maejam(Nk-kum)",
        "Maejam(Nok-nk-kum)",
        "Maejan(Khan-aew-u)",
        "Muang-nan",
        "Sri-sat-shanalai",
    ],
    "model_Predicted": model
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["y_Actual", "model_Predicted"])
confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(
    df["y_Actual"],
    df["model_Predicted"],
    rownames=["Actual"],
    colnames=["Predicted"],
    margins=False,
)

sn.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

And this is the result. Which is not right.

[Problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoOQV.png)

Result should being like this. Atleast not full score and have some mistake.

[What result suppose to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgZYF.png)

I import h5 dataset, I don't know what I miss and what I should do next.

Comment: Your "model_Predicted" variable in the dataframe is the model itself, not any data.

Comment: I already add my dataset link, and put [model] into "model_Predicted", so it should redirect to that link. My question is what I done wrong.

Comment: `model` contains your model, not your model's output.

Comment: It's not model output, it's the link where my model is. There's no funchion about model outpost here.